# Where is the menu to set origin to geometry?

Tags: geometry, origin

Where is the menu to set origin to geometry?

The guy in a tutorial bring it up on a menu and I can't find it on 3.0. Is it an add-on?

I'm new to blender so I'm a bit confused about were he is selecting this *origin to geometry* in the picture.

I'm trying to make a eye ball with texture.

[image: screen shot of menu for setting origin]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set the origin to the objects geometry, first select the object. Then on the top left-ish of the 3d viewport, click on the object button. Then go down to, set origin, and then select, origin to geometry. Make sure you are in object mode when doing this. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways.  Here's one that you can do with just the mouse:  In *Object* mode Left-click to select the object then Right-click to bring up this menu:

[image: Object Context Menu]

got to *Set Origin* and select the type you want. In your case that's *Origin to Geometry*

Comment: You can also right-click anywhere in the 3d View window in Object mode and the Set Origin menu is near the top of that popup menu.